# prove a sequence diverges to infinity

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-writing

I want to prove $$ \frac{2^n}{n^2} + (-1)^n \to \infty $$ I know that $ (-1)^n $ serves as a distractor here since it wouldn't affect the result as $ n \to \infty $. I try to come up with a sequence that's smaller than the one above and show that it diverges to infinity but fail to do so. I suppose I can utilize the idea $ \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n} \to c $ such that $ c > 1 $ to show that $ x_n \to \infty $ but don't know where to start. Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $$a_n=\frac{2^n}{n^2}$$

then

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=2$$

So, for $ n\ge N$, (great enough) $$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}>\frac 32$$

$$\frac{a_n}{a_{n-1}}>\frac 32$$
....
$$\frac{a_{N+1}}{a_N}>\frac 32$$
thus

$$a_n>(\frac 32)^{n-N-1}$$
hence
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}a_n=+\infty$$

but

$$\frac{2^n}{n^2}+(-1)^n\ge a_n-1$$
done.

Comment: This is exactly what I was thinking about but keep stucking. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

$$ \frac{2^n}{n^2} + (-1)^n \geq \frac{2^n}{n^2} - 1  $$
so \begin{align*}
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{2^n}{n^2} + (-1)^n &\geq \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left( \frac{2^n}{n^2} - 1 \right)  \\
    &= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left( \frac{2^n - n^2}{n^2} \right)  \\
    &\overset{L'H}{=} \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left( \frac{\ln(2) 2^n - 2n}{2n} \right)  \\
    &\overset{L'H}{=} \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left( \frac{\ln^2(2) 2^n - 2}{2} \right)  \\
    &= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left( \ln^2(2) 2^{n-1} - 1 \right)  \\
    &= \infty  \text{.}
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you. I know that we can use  l'hopital to find the limit is actually infinity but I wasn't sure if it is consider as a rigorous proof rather than just calculation.

Comment: If you have a proof of l'Hopital's rule, then it is a valid tool in a proof.  Additionally, a calculation is a proof.  How else would you prove $1 + 1 = 2$?